# Leveling up in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast leveling and easy experience farming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85107/fast-leveling-and-easy-experience-farming)

Anyone know of a sweet spot on Pandora where one can grind out some levels? I'd like my baby, Maya, at her full potential as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your level!
Both arenas are very good. Fight until last wave, then die to restart and get xp again. if you did 1 or 2 levels, proceed with the mission and do the same with the next. Every mission has a bit higher monster level.