# Which is better: side quests after killing the warrior or Playthrough 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

My question is, once I beat the warrior should I do all the sidequests in Normal before starting TVHM or should I go right to TVHM once it becomes available?

I just bought the game and have been playing with some friends who are higher level than me so that we could enjoy the Tiny Tina DLC together.  As a result, I leveled up pretty fast without doing much of the main story quest or side quests.

Now I'm a level 32 commando and haven't finished the main storyline in normal (Just finished "Where angels fear to treat Pt 2").  I get almost no XP from kills on missions.  I still have tons of sidequests.  I imagine some of them might give good loot, or be fun to play.  It it better to go to Playthrough 2 or should i do the sidequests in Normal first?

EDIT: changed question title and some wording for clarity

Comment: This [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85107/fast-leveling-and-easy-experience-farming) may help you.

Comment: Which question are you asking?  How long it takes to get to 50?  Or if you should do TVHM after finishing the first playthrough?

Comment: As long as you need, depending on your play style

Comment: Related, perhaps dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work.  It doesn't list around what level Playthrough 2 starts at, but I believe it's ~35 or so.

Comment: @fbueckert my question is asking if it's more beneficial to do side quests in normal vs starting playthrough 2 (TVHM).

Comment: Playthrough 1 doesn't scale at all.  If you want level-appropriate loot, you have to do level-appropriate quests.

Comment: Playthrough 2 is at a weird place between 35 and 40. I would say doing sidequests is more beneficial than going to Playthrough 2 immediately just for sake of sanity. I'm not 'answering' as I have no conclusive data besides my own experience. If you have access to post-game DLC (Hammerlock and Tiny Tina iirc) that's even better.

Comment: @Reafexus thanks, that's exactly what i wanted to know.  I've got the DLCs and wasn't sure if it made sense to bang through those before playthrough 2 or after.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments to my question above, I think the question has been answered.

Playthrough 1 sidequests don't adjust to your level after beating the warrior.  So it doesn't make sense to go back to sidequests in Normal since enemies and quests will be too low level.  (As per @fbueckert)

DLC quests do scale so it does make sense to do these quests in playthrough 1 (Normal) mode before heading to Playthrough 2 (TVHM).  (As per @Reafexus)

Comment: They max out at either 35 or 38 or something like that. (And only the post game ones). Scarlet and Torgue DLC's are mid game DLC's and stop before level 30. I don't remember the exact levels though.